# How do I get multiple selectors to populate from one app.component.ts file?

Tags: angular, css-selectors, components

I am trying to use two selectors on an angular 8 website. HTML would have something like

```
<jk-header></jk-header> some html <jk-main-content></jk-main-content>
```

with an app.component.ts as follows.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jk-header',
  templateUrl: './app.HomePageHeader.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'jk';
}

@Component({
    selector: 'jk-main-content',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class JkApp extends AppComponent {
}
```

Only the jk-header gets populated. Tried many different things but none worked. Cannot find any documentation on this. HELP!!!!

Here is app.component.html:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:#666666">
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="text-center" style="color:white" text-size:4">
     Attorney At Law
    <br>
    address, <br>
    locale<br>
    Telephone:nnnnnnnn <br>
    Facsimile: nnnnnn <br>
    Email:<a href="mailto:xxxxx"> xxxxx</a>><br>
    <a href="directions.htm">
      <span style="color:#660000">
        For
        directions to our office click here</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you post `app.component.html` code?

Comment: try creating a demo on stack blitz to reproduce the issue

Comment: Added app.component.html. Thanks Plochie!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to accomplish here, it looks like you are confusing alot of Angular's patterns. You should not change what are in the object in `@Component` unless you have a very good reason to do so. I recommend you spend a couple of hours on Angular Tutorial Tour of Heroes : https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `JkApp(jk-main-content)` into **bootstrap** array in your app.module.ts file to load your both `<jk-header>` & `<jk-main-content>` component

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, JkApp ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent, JkApp ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndfz9p

Comment: Perfect - that did it! Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check as right for this answere? so you know this would be helpful for other users also if they are facing this kind of issue.

Comment: Adding JkApp to declarations and bootstrap in app.module.ts fixed the problem. Your answer was perfect. Thank you Codeptive Solutions!